# DisplayMember property from base class in combobox

Tags: c#, .net, combobox

I use Windows Forms. I want DisplayMember equal property from base class?
I have class

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Type Type { get; set; }
}
```

I want, that my comboBox show Type.Name.

```
List<MyViewModel> list = new List<MyViewModel>();
list.Add(new MyViewModel(){ Id = 1, Type.GetType(int)});
list.Add(new MyViewModel(){ Id = 2, Type.GetType(string)});
//how i must to config displayMember???
myComboBox.DisplayMember = "Type.Name";
myComboBox.ValueMember = "Id";
myComboBox.DataSoutce = list;
```

But i can't get Type.Name for display in comboBox. Can you help me?

Comment: Type it's System.Type

Comment: Do you use the Type property somewhere else in your code? Because if no, it would be easier for you to store just its Name.

Comment: I need Id and Type. Right now, my class has an additional field of Name, from which I want to get rid of.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `ComboBox` has an event for this purpose called `Format`:

```
myComboBox.DisplayMember = "Type";//Notice this
myComboBox.Format += (s,e) => {
    e.Value = ((Type)e.Value).Name;
};
```

Comment: ((Type)e.Value).Name  Cannot cast '((System.Windows.Forms.ConvertEventArgs)(e)).Value' (which has an actual type of 'EditorX.Model.ViewOfTable') to 'System.Type' string

Comment: @Mikhail what is your `DisplayMember`? be sure it is `"Type"` as I noticed in my code.

Comment: Really, your code is working. Thanks. But it's hard code in my opinion. It's the only way?

Comment: @Mikhail why do you think it's hard code? `Format` event is added for that purpose. It's the only `simplest` way. a `TextBox` even doesn't have that event. Only `ListControl` has, `ComboBox` inherits from `ListControl`.

Comment: Because i think that myComboBox.DisplayMember = "Type.Name"
not hard code, but it's no work.

Answer (score 1):

you must create a new class which has two properties:

```
class MyViewModel
{
    public string TypeName {get; set; }
    public string Id {get; set; }
}

// generate the datasource list.
List<MyViewModel> list = new List<MyViewModel>();
list.Add(new MyViewModel(){ Id = 1, TypeName = typeof(int).Name});
list.Add(new MyViewModel(){ Id = 2, TypeName = typeof(string).Name});

// how i must to config displayMember
myComboBox.DisplayMember = "TypeName";
myComboBox.ValueMember = "Id";
myComboBox.DataSoutce = list;
```

Comment: On the contrary I want to get rid of excess property.

Comment: I meet the same question too,I used the method to solve the problem.